# Crosstab function in postgres not returning any values in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab, pgadmin

I'm trying to create a pivot table in pgadmin 4 using the crosstab function. I've successfully created one by copying code (see below) from a postgres manual just to make sure the tablefunc extension was installed / able to work correctly:

```
create table sales(year int, month int, qty int);
insert into sales values(2007, 1, 1000);
insert into sales values(2007, 2, 1500);
insert into sales values(2007, 7, 500);
insert into sales values(2007, 11, 1500);
insert into sales values(2007, 12, 2000);
insert into sales values(2008, 1, 1000);

SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  $$ SELECT year, month, qty FROM sales ORDER BY 1 $$,
  $$ SELECT m FROM generate_series(1,12) m $$
) AS (
      year int,
      "Jan" int,
      "Feb" int,
      "Mar" int,
      "Apr" int,
      "May" int,
      "Jun" int,
      "Jul" int,
      "Aug" int,
      "Sep" int,
      "Oct" int,
      "Nov" int,
      "Dec" int
    );
     year | Jan  | Feb  | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov  | Dec
    ------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------
     2007 | 1000 | 1500 |     |     |     |     | 500 |     |     |     | 1500 | 2000
     2008 | 1000 |      |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |
```

however, when trying to import my own data, the table returns blank values:

```
select *
from medclaims2
```

output:

```
member  date    paid_amount icd9
1   7/30/2011   43075   ICD9-1
2   8/16/2011   24895   ICD9-2
3   3/7/2012    18957   ICD9-4
4   8/16/2011   37476   ICD9-5


SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  $$ SELECT member, icd9, paid_amount FROM medclaims2  $$,
  $$ SELECT m FROM generate_series(1,4) m $$
) AS (
  member varchar(25), "ICD9-1" varchar(25),"ICD9-2" varchar(25),"ICD9-4" int,"ICD9-5" varchar(25)
);
```

output:

```
 member ICD9-1  ICD9-2  ICD9-4  ICD9-5
    1               
    2               
    3               
    4
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a typo?

```
Paid_Amouint
```

vs.

```
Paid_Amount
```

Regards
Ralph